# Difference between Function field and AddressOfData field in IMAGE_THUNK_DATA structure?

Tags: c++, windows, portable-executable

I'm trying the code example in PE format, but there's a portion of the code that look like this

```
auto iatArr = (IMAGE_THUNK_DATA*)(exeBuf + offset_impAddrArr);
        for (int i = 0; i < len_iatCallVia; iatArr++,i++) {
            if (auto nameRVA = iatArr->u1.Function) {
                PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME k = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)(exeBuf + rvaToOffset(exeBuf, nameRVA));
                printf("[+] imported API -- %s (hint = %i)\n", &k->Name, k->Hint);

            }
        }
```

So the problem is I'm wondering why the author use the "Function" field instead of AddressOfData, cuz I thought the Function field stored the address of the function, then why the address can be cast into PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME directly ??

I've googled some information about the structure of IMAGE_THUNK_DATA and IAT kind of stuff but all I found are people focusing on how to use IAT, the only I found a little bit useful is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2002/march/inside-windows-an-in-depth-look-into-the-win32-portable-executable-file-format-part-2) it tells that

```
DWORD Function;       // Memory address of the imported function
DWORD AddressOfData;  // RVA to an IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME with the imported API name
```

Comment: Sure, use u1.AddressOfData.  u1 is a union so the author surely never noticed the bug.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you have any clues that why "Function" can be cast into IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME ?

Comment: There is no auto in `C`. It is C++

Comment: @0___________Thanks for reminding

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which field you use because `IMAGE_THUNK_DATA` structure encapsulates its elements in an union and all fields are the type of `DWORD` which is 4-byte signed integer.

The definition for `IMAGE_THUNK_DATA32`:

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_THUNK_DATA32
{
    union
    {
        DWORD ForwarderString;
        DWORD Function;
        DWORD Ordinal;
        DWORD AddressOfData;
    }u1;
}IMAGE_THUNK_DATA32;
```

However, it matters when it comes to semantic reasons. When you traverse the original `IAT` (the table that the field `OriginalFirstThunk` in `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` points to), which contains the `RVA`s to the elements of an array of `IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME`structures, you should refer to the field `AddressOfData` but when you parse the `IAT` (the table that the field `FirstThunk` in `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` points to) which contains the actual function addresses loaded by OS Image Loader, you should refer to the field `Function`.

Comment: I thought OriginalFirstThunk points to INT or HNT ?

Comment: OriginalFirstThunk points to Import Lookup Table and FirstThunk points to Import Address Table which contains the actual function addresses loaded by Image Loader. Both tables have the same number of entries.

Comment: It's the same thing INT equals Import Lookup Table according to this post https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16870/import-table-vs-import-address-table